# PHP Paypal standard integration

Tags: php, paypal

I'm in UK and setting up a PHP website selling physical products. I will initially use Paypal standard integration. I have a bespoke cart already setup and I get customer's address on my website so that I can include a shipping cost to the order before transferring the cart data over to Paypal. Getting the shipping address on my site is ok but how do I then transfer that to Paypal without the user needing to re-enter it or changing it afterwards ?

Answer (score 1):

The ideal ecommerce solution is to display the PayPal Checkout "shortcut" button as early as possible in your flow, before a shipping address is even entered (perhaps on a final "View Cart" or configured product page), and implement an `onShippingChange` listener to patch the order as needed.

Here is documentation:

- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/shipping-callback/
- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/configure-payments/shipping-options/#shipping-callback-with-shipping-options

This way, the buyer does not have to manually type in an address if it's already stored in PayPal, resulting in quicker checkouts and increased conversion (more sales due to less friction in the checkout process)

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'll investigate that. I was assuming that I could get customer to complete the shipping address on my site so that I could calculate the shipping cost and then transfer that data to paypal along with the cart data. I don't know which variables I would need to send for shipping address and whether I'd need to use address_override.

Comment: When creating a v2 order, in the purchase_units you can include a `shipping` object. If you also specify an application_context (outside of purchase_units) with a shipping_preference of SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS, that provided address must be used. The checkout will fail with an error if the provided address is not valid for PayPal.

Comment: The early shortcut to PayPal (before entering an address) and use of `onShippingChange` is a superior experience, so you're better off doing that